require() of ES Module node_modules/remark-gfm/index.js from .cache/compiled/gatsby-config.js not supported
I am trying to create some dynamic pages from mdx in gatsby, using below code
import { compileMDX } from 'gatsby-plugin-mdx';
import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm';

const mdxContent = await compileMDX(
    { absolutePath, source: content.toString() },
    {
        outputFormat: 'function-body',
        jsxRuntime: 'automatic',
        jsx: false,
        useDynamicImport: true,
        remarkPlugins: [remarkGfm]
    }, cache, reporter
)

But it doesn't seem to be working, I read at https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/37069 that gatsby compies gatsby-node.ts to CommonJs module. Getting below error -
Failed to import compiled file ".cache/compiled/gatsby-node.js" after retry, attempting
another retry (#2 of 5) - "require() of ES Module node_modules/remark-gfm/index.js from .cache/compiled/gatsby-config.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in .cache/compiled/gatsby-config.js to a dynamic import()
 which is available in all CommonJS modules."

I tried changing to dynamic import but still getting the same error
const remarkGfm = await import('remark-gfm')
const mdxContent = await compileMDX(
    { absolutePath, source: content.toString() },
    {
        outputFormat: 'function-body',
        jsxRuntime: 'automatic',
        jsx: false,
        useDynamicImport: true,
        remarkPlugins: [remarkGfm.default]// tried [remarkGfm] as well
    }, cache, reporter
)

I feel like something else is wrong and its possibly misleading error. Any help on this would be highly appreciated thanks.

An error message is not code and shouldn't use code formatting...

Thanks for the comment, I feel it helpful to keep the error more readable and clear. Code formatting helps doing that.

Can you post the file type used?

I was using typescript, .ts files.
